# ManageBean Object initialize null

Tags: java, jsf, ejb, managed-bean

I am setting values to object in xhtml, but it becoming to null in managed bean.

"Users" entity has many-to-many relation with "Groups" entity so in the form I reload "Groups" from db dynamically but after clicking command button "user" object becoming to null.

Here is my xhtml :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Kullanıcı İşlemleri</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="addUser">
        <p:panel header="Kullanıcı Tanımlama">
            <p:messages autoUpdate="true"/>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                Adı:<p:inputText value="#{userBean.user.name}"/>
                Soyadı : <p:inputText value="#{userBean.user.surname}"/>
                Kullanıcı Adı : <p:inputText value="#{userBean.user.username}"/>
                E-mail: <p:inputText value="#{userBean.user.email}"/>
                Parola : <p:password value="#{userBean.user.password}"/>
                Kullanıcı Tipi: 
                <p:selectManyCheckbox value="#{userBean.user.groupsCollection}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{userBean.groupList}" var="grp" itemLabel="#{grp.groupName}" itemValue="#{grp.groupId}"/>
                </p:selectManyCheckbox>

                <p:commandButton value="Kullanıcıyı Ekle" action="#{userBean.persist()}" process="@this" update="@form" />

            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Managed Bean :

```
package com.mkmturizm.bean;

import com.mkmturizm.entity.Groups;
import com.mkmturizm.entity.Users;
import com.mkmturizm.service.GroupService;
import com.mkmturizm.service.UserService;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class UserBean implements Serializable {

private Users user = new Users();
private List<Groups> groupList = new ArrayList<Groups>();

@EJB
UserService userService;
@EJB
GroupService groupService;

public void persist() throws Exception
{

    userService.persist(user);
    user = new Users();

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Kayıt başarıyla gerçeklerşti", ""));

}

@PostConstruct
public void getAllGroups()
{
    groupList = groupService.groupsList();
}

public List<Groups> getGroupList()
{
    return groupList;
}

public void setGroupList(List<Groups> groupList)
{
    this.groupList = groupList;
}

public Users getUser()
{
    return user;
}

public void setUser(Users user)
{
    this.user = user;
}
}
```

UPDATE : (RESLOVED)

I changed value of selected items as grp because I am sending id of group so it can't cast Groups object but can't throw any exception. After that I wrote a custom converter and I guess custom converters could work well before I have changed xhtml.

```
<f:selectItems value="#{userBean.groupList}" var="grp" itemLabel="#{grp.groupName}" itemValue="#{grp}"/>
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace or any error message related to the problem.

Comment: There is not any error message. I remove selectManyCheckBox block from xhtml and @Postconstruct it works well. How can I load selectManyCheckBox dynamically ?

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code you u r adding data to the checkbox list

Comment: I am getting group list in getAllGroups() and I am using  in <p:selectManyCheckbox/>

Comment: Try to initialize all your fields in the `@PostConstruct` bean instead of initializing them in class constructor or at declaration.

Comment: I create a init method but I get same result user object initialize null . Any other thing I have to add process attribute to command button when I use manyCheckBox. If I don't add process"@this" nothing happen.
  
@PostConstruct
    private void init()
    {
        user = new Users();
        groupList = groupService.groupsList();
    }

Comment: You try to add user and you use  `userBean.user.groupsCollection` in  `value property of selectManyCheckbox `.I think you have problem with this part

Comment: @justauser I think so but first call of page if I use PostCostruct it sets null user's fields. I set ajax="false" at commandbutton and I get this error :
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: /admin/userOperation.xhtml 25,85 value="#{userBean.user.groupsCollection}": The class 'com.mkmturizm.entity.Users' does not have a writable property 'groupsCollection'.